# assign values to variables using react hooks inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**If you think this question is stupid, sorry for that and please forgive me because iam Beginner.:)**

**1) I want to declare variables using react hooks i done like this:**

```
const[adata,setAdata]=useState(   
                    name:"",
                    companyname: ""
                  })
```

2)I want to assign " name" to the value(name=filteredperson.name,companyname=filteredperson.companyname) that inside map function
here, map function code:

```
    {data.map((filteredPerson, index) => (
<td>{filteredperson.name}</td>
<td>{filteredperson.companyname}</td>
```

3)Finally,so i assigned my map function values to variables using react hooks, i want to print it on console.

**for eg:name:{filteredperson.name} value in console**

Note:filteredperson is a map function. I want to assign map values to variables that are using react hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` variable is of type `{name: string, companyname: string}`, so to assign value to this variable, you call the setter function:

`setData({name: NAME_VALUE, companyname: COMPANYNAME_VALUE})`

After you set the value of this object, you can print the values with:

`console.log(data.name)`
`console.log(data.companyname)`